# German sharp S or eszett

Tags: support, unicode

How can I write the German sharp S or 'eszett' (ß) in a question here?

In LaTeX it is written like `{\ss}` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11443/how-to-type-the-%C3%9F-and-capital-%C3%9F-%E1%BA%9E-on-a-windows-8-german-keyboard It can just be typed: ß

Comment: An eszett isn't a "B" (although it looks like one), it's a "long S"

Comment: @Cai: The name *long s* is reserved for [this: ſ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s).

Comment: @Wrzl oh yeh, I meant "sharp S", not sure why I said that... the important point is, it's not a "B"

Comment: On the most common German keyboard layout, it is right from the "0". You don't need more tricks, it is part of the ordinary latin1 code table, it is essentially a character with accents like ö.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Exchange has full Unicode support. This means you just need to type the character into the post body, or copy it from somewhere.

In Windows, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Num2</kbd> + <kbd>Num2</kbd> + <kbd>Num5</kbd>, or using the character map.

In macOS, you can long press <kbd>S</kbd> to get it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the HTML entity: `&szlig;` produces ß. Or just copy it over from other posts, since it's part of Unicode.

Comment: The HTML entity will work in Questions and in Answers, but not in comments.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Luckily the OP asked how to write it in a *question*...

Comment: `&szlig;` doesn’t work in titles. Although, you could just copy-paste one `ß` from the post to the title.

Answer (score 9):

I have my keyboard set for US-International, rather than the default EN-US layout. On a US-INT keyboard, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> produces the ß. Note that the US-INT keyboard does not support the recently-defined *uppercase* ß (ẞ); for that, I had to hack together an AutoHotKey script.

(<kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the *right* <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.)